# Scala ListViewSelectionChange event outputs unexpected range

Tags: swing, scala, listview, selectionchanged, scala-swing

I'm currently trying to use a scala.swing.ListView in a Scala application.

I basically want to get the selected item of a ListView, as soon as the selection changes.

Here a sample which can be pasted into the Scala prompt.

```
import scala.swing._

class MainView extends MainFrame {

  import ListView._
  val selector = new ListView(List[Int]()) {
    renderer = Renderer(x => x.toString)
    selection.reactions += {
      case event.ListSelectionChanged(source, range, _) =>
        if(!range.isEmpty) {
          println("selection " + range)
        }
    }
    selection.intervalMode = IntervalMode.Single
  }

  selector.listData = 1 +: selector.listData
  selector.listData = 2 +: selector.listData
  selector.listData = 3 +: selector.listData
  selector.listData = 4 +: selector.listData
  selector.listData = 5 +: selector.listData

  contents = new GridBagPanel(){
    layout(new ScrollPane(selector))  = new Constraints() {
      gridx = 0
      gridy = 0
      weighty = 1
      fill = GridBagPanel.Fill.Vertical
    }
  }
  visible = true
}

var view = new MainView()
```

If I would now select the first element in the list, I would expect `Range` to contain only `0`, if I then select the second element, I would expect only `1` and so on.

However, if I select the first and then the second element, `Range` contains `(0, 1)`. If I select the fifth and then the third element, range contains `(2, 3, 4)`.

So, range contains always the range between the last and the current selected item, in ascending order.

Sadly, the [Scala documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/scala-swing/index.html#scala.swing.event.ListSelectionChanged) does not state how this API works.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Might this be the wrong event for reacting on `ListView` selection changes?

Comment: What exactly do you want? If you want all selected items, you can do `selection.items`.

Comment: I want to get the selected item. If I access selection.items(0) from within the event handler, I always get the first item of the list, regardless of which item is selected.

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed you use `ListSelectionChanged`. I personally never used that. You can try `SelectionChanged` instead.

Comment: Still no luck. Could you post your working code as an answer?

Comment: Here is a small working example. (http://pastebin.com/kdv9CDfd) However I did not put the reactions inside the `ListView` instance.

Comment: Now it gets really strange - I used your code 1:1, just changed the data type, still does not work as expected. Hm. I might have some strange side-effect somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57715/discussion-between-kigyo-and-emiswelt).